# how to control webpack-dev-server generate script src like localhost:3000/static/js/xxx.js?

Tags: webpack-dev-server

when I use cra create a react app and npm run start, I see the dom tree like beblow

[image]

but for some special reason I hope it should be like

[image]

does anybody know how to change the `webpackDevServer.config.js` to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried already to modify the base-href value in your index.html?

```html
<base href="./">
```

With this, it will take the files from whatever server or directory you run your app from.

Also, if you need it set to that always, you could try:

```html
<base href="http://localhost:3000/">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by using `output` property in your webpack.config.js file.
You can do something like this,

```
const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'point_to_static_folder')
output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/static/",
}
```

For your other files you can define rules to have those files as well.